# I can't solve the Error 404 in Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a problem with Laravel. I did a route and a few day ago it worked fine, but now I don't know why not. I'm working whit Livewire, so in the route file this is my code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Livewire;

Route::get('/dashboard', [Admin\AdminController::class, 'index']) -> name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/productos', Livewire\Admin\ProductList::class) -> name('admin.products');
Route::get('/productos/crear', Livewire\Admin\ProductCreate::class) -> name('admin.products.create');
Route::get('/productos/editar/{product}', Livewire\Admin\ProductEdit::class) -> name('admin.products.edit');
Route::post('/productos/fotos/{product}', [Admin\ProductController::class, 'photos']) -> name('admin.products.photos');
```

All routes work, but not '/productos/crear'. It appear a 404 error.

And this is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Subcategory;
use App\Models\Brand;

class ProductCreate extends Component
{

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.product-create');
    }
}
```

I reviewed all filenames to make sure that they are correct.

Comment: Everything seems alright. Maybe you should try to return a different view. If it works, it must be a naming issue.

Comment: I solved it, i put my solution in other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another routes file, where the first part is a variable, the second part is "products", and the 3rd part is a slug. That conflicted with "admin/products/create" and redirected to 404 page.